# how to show webcams at a same time using in c++ winform using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, opencv, clr

I want to Show my webcam on two different pictureBox using threads.
But the problem is on pictureBox is showing the webcam while the other one is just showing a static picture of the webcam.
I want both pictureBoxes to show the webcam at the same time but i wanted done using threads to improve the performance.
Any ideas how to fix it?
it'll be greatly appreciated;

Here is the Code

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

Mat _frame1;

Mat _frame2;

bool s1 = false;
bool s2 = false;

void start_picture_Box1()
{
    s1 = true;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (s1) {
        cap >> _frame1;

        mat2picture bimapconvert;
        this->pictureBox1->Image = bimapconvert.Mat2Bimap(_frame1);

        pictureBox1->Refresh();
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void start_picture_Box2()
{
    s2 = true;
    VideoCapture cap1(0);
    while (s2) {
        cap1 >> _frame2;

        mat2picture bimapconvert;
        this->pictureBox2->Image = bimapconvert.Mat2Bimap(_frame2);

        pictureBox2->Refresh();
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public: void picture_Box1()

{
    Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::start_picture_Box1));
}

 public: void picture_Box2()
 {
     Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::start_picture_Box2));
 }


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod1 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::picture_Box1);
ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod2 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::picture_Box2);
Thread^ MyThread1 = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod1);
Thread^ MyThread2 = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod2);
MyThread1->Start();
MyThread2->Start();

}
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
s1 = false;
s2 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are doing VideoCapture in both the images which are taking input from different sources.

It will be better if you do Video Capture on your main thread and store image from the webcam in a frame and send that to different threads that you want.

Comment: can you pls show me a sample code? im so stuck in this program